Can't sign in with Spotify (Deployed on Vercel)

I created a music listening web using nextjs14, prisma, next-auth, and Spotify API.
tried deploying using vercel and resolved the errors that appeared intermittently and there were no errors in the log.
If you press the login button and click the agree button to link with Spotify, the login does not proceed properly and returns to the login page again.

Locally, after executing (npm run dev, npm build, npm start), login and other functions work normally.
I tried several things throughout the day while searching on Google.

Add NEXTAUTH_URL environment variable

Add "scripts": { "postinstall": "prisma generate" } in package.json

Add next.config.mjs cors settings

tried redeploy


I hope the login works properly....
Github repo
https://github.com/Simon1476/next-meloquiz
